# Is this a plug-in in wordpress  or a custom JavaScript

Tags: plugins

On the www.valendesigns.com website I like the JavaScript (I think that's what it is) near the top of the page where when you click on one of the three images, it rotates to the front.

Does anyone know if this is a plug-in?  If so do you know where I can get it?  If it is not a plug-in, does anyone know where I can learn how to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the look of the site's source code:

```
<!-- Scripts --> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 
<script src="http://valendesigns.com/wp-content/themes/valen/js/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script> 

[...later in the source...]

<div id="panel"> 
            <img src="http://valendesigns.com/wp-content/themes/valen/images/panel/left_slide.png" id="left_slide" alt="" /> 
      <img src="http://valendesigns.com/wp-content/themes/valen/images/panel/center_slide.png" id="center_slide" alt="" /> 
      <img src="http://valendesigns.com/wp-content/themes/valen/images/panel/right_slide.png" id="right_slide" alt="" /> 
        </div> 
        <span class="get_quote"><a href="http://valendesigns.com/contact">Get a Quote</a></span> 

    </div>
```

I would say that it is either running from the jQuery that was imported in the header of the page, or  a custom-built slider within the theme. These built-in sliders are quite popular now.

Comment: Isn't that what the answer says? That the slider is either using jQuery or a custom implementation?

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I had to reread the question and your answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### The Panel Slider is custom javascript by the developer of the site.

The javascript is output in the footer of the source and I also found it on **[Snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view/14169/panel-silder-con-jquery/)** but couldn't find any license information except the copyright on the Valen site.

You would need to get permission from the **[author](http://valendesigns.com/about/)** to use it.